# Copy and rename the Stored Procedure by using SQL server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Greetings for the day!!

My requirement is we have Stored procedures created with one ID in database now i need to copy the script of Stored procedure created with existing ID and rename it with New ID.

Is there any SQL server Query to do above process.

PS:i am aware about sp_helptext. looking for SQL script.

Thank you.

Comment: EXEC SP_RENAME 'SP_NAME', 'NEW_SP_NAME', this one is for renaming and from there you can probably take it further

Comment: Also, you can snag the text of the procedures from sys.all_sql_modules